# python app engine restful service using DAL

Tags: python, google-app-engine, rest, data-access-layer

I am building a restful service in python for app engine and I would like to be able to separate datastore operations (like queries) from the request handlers.

I can build my own DAL, but I'm wondering if there are libraries already out there. Anyone know of any or have suggestions on how to build one? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you want to be able to port transparently between App Engine and other platforms? If not, App Engine already provides one, in the form of the google.appengine.ext.db package.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something portable outside Google App Engine you could try the [Web2Py](http://www.web2py.com/book/default/chapter/06#The-Database-Abstraction-Layer) DAL Api.

You would code something like this:

```
db = DAL('gae')
rows = db(db.mytable.myfield!=None).select()

for row in rows:
  print row.myfield
```

Web2py currently supports these db flavors:

> Google App Engine
>   SQLite
>   MySQL
>   PostgreSQL
>   MSSQL
>   FireBird
>   Oracle
>   DB2
>   Ingres
>   Informix